# intensity of a specific coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, coordinate

I have a rectangular image and I want to find the intensities of the rectangle corners? Is there any **function to give the mean intensity of specific coordinates in an image**?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry to forgot, I'm using MATLAB.

Comment: How do you get the image? (imread?) Is it grayscale or RGB? Do you know how to find the coordinates of the corners? Do you have any code? Please read [ask].

Comment: As it stands this question can't be answered. Of course its possible to find the mean intensity of some pixels if we know the coordinates (sum of intensities divided by number of coordinates). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).